# How Can i do a simple login with spring boot + JPA without spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking for a way for send the object user to a indexController for do a *Query* on Usuarios table if match a user in the table the object user won't be null  and the controller redirect to another page. but i have a issue when i fill the login form with the username and password.

```
2018-06-17 19:54:28.254  WARN 14012 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.solutionslab.springboot.app.models.entity.Usuario'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'jlhiciano'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "jlhiciano"
2018-06-17 19:54:28.254  WARN 14012 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.solutionslab.springboot.app.models.entity.Usuario'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'jlhiciano'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "jlhiciano"
```

If i put in username a number like a id 1 jpa find the user, but i don't wanna put the id instead the username.

here is the code:

**My controller**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@Autowired
IUsuarioDao usuarioDao;

@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("titulo", "Inicio");
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(Map<String,Object> model) {
    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    model.put("usuario", user);
    model.put("titulo", "login");
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String log(Usuario usuario) {

    Usuario user = usuarioDao.findByUsuarioAndClave(usuario.getUsuario(), usuario.getClave());


    if(user == null) 
        return "redirect:login";
    else
        return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

The method log is only for test that read in the dababase.

**userDao class**

```
public interface IUsuarioDao extends CrudRepository<Usuario, Long>{

@Query("SELECT u.usuario FROM Usuario u where u.usuario = :usuario and u.clave = :clave")
public Usuario findByUsuarioAndClave(@Param("usuario") String usuario,@Param("clave") String clave);}
```

**Service Interface usuario **

```
public interface IUsuarioService {
public List<Usuario> findAll();

public void save(Usuario usuario);

public Usuario findOne(Long id);

public void delete(Long id);

public Usuario findByUsuarioAndClave(String usuario,String clave);}
```

**Implementing usuario service**

```
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements IUsuarioService {

@Autowired
private IUsuarioDao usuarioDao;

@Override
public List<Usuario> findAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (List<Usuario>) usuarioDao.findAll();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(Usuario usuario) {
    usuarioDao.save(usuario);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Usuario findOne(Long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return usuarioDao.findOne(id);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(Long id) {
    usuarioDao.delete(id);

}

@Override
public Usuario findByUsuarioAndClave(String usuario, String clave) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return usuarioDao.findByUsuarioAndClave(usuario, clave);
}
}
```

**Login page**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="layout/layout :: head"></head>
<body>
    <header th:replace="layout/layout :: header"></header>
    <div class="container">
    <form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${usuario}" method="post">
        <label for="usuario">Username</label>: 
        <input type="text" th:field="*{usuario}" autofocus="autofocus" /> <br/> 
        <label for="clave">Password</label>: 
        <input type="password" th:field="*{clave}" /> <br /> 
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<footer th:replace="layout/layout :: footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Usuario Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String nombre;

@NotNull
private String identificacion;

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date nacimiento;

@NotNull
private String usuario;

@Null
private String web;

@Null
private String facebook;

@Null
private String referencia;

@Null
private String instagram;

@Null
private String twitter;

@Null
private String foto;

@NotNull
private String clave;

@Null
private int codigo_postal;

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date fecha_registro;

@NotNull
private String telefono;

@NotNull
private String direccion;

@NotNull
private boolean estado;

@Null
private String detalle;

@Null
private String pasaporte;

@NotNull
private String celular;

@Null
private String whatsapp;

@NotNull
private String correo;

@NotNull
private long codigo_usuario_registro;

@NotNull
private long codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion;

@Null
private long codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion;

@Null
private long codigo_tipo_registro_categoria;

@Null
private long codigo_tipo_registro_empresa;

@NotNull
private String sexo;

/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getIdentificacion() {
    return identificacion;
}

public void setIdentificacion(String identificacion) {
    this.identificacion = identificacion;
}

public Date getNacimiento() {
    return nacimiento;
}

public void setNacimiento(Date nacimiento) {
    this.nacimiento = nacimiento;
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getWeb() {
    return web;
}

public void setWeb(String web) {
    this.web = web;
}

public String getFacebook() {
    return facebook;
}

public void setFacebook(String facebook) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
}

public String getReferencia() {
    return referencia;
}

public void setReferencia(String referencia) {
    this.referencia = referencia;
}

public String getInstagram() {
    return instagram;
}

public void setInstagram(String instagram) {
    this.instagram = instagram;
}

public String getTwitter() {
    return twitter;
}

public void setTwitter(String twitter) {
    this.twitter = twitter;
}

public String getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(String foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}

public String getClave() {
    return clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}

public int getCodigo_postal() {
    return codigo_postal;
}

public void setCodigo_postal(int codigo_postal) {
    this.codigo_postal = codigo_postal;
}

public Date getFecha_registro() {
    return fecha_registro;
}

public void setFecha_registro(Date fecha_registro) {
    this.fecha_registro = fecha_registro;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public boolean isEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public String getDetalle() {
    return detalle;
}

public void setDetalle(String detalle) {
    this.detalle = detalle;
}

public String getPasaporte() {
    return pasaporte;
}

public void setPasaporte(String pasaporte) {
    this.pasaporte = pasaporte;
}

public String getCelular() {
    return celular;
}

public void setCelular(String celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

public String getWhatsapp() {
    return whatsapp;
}

public void setWhatsapp(String whatsapp) {
    this.whatsapp = whatsapp;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public long getCodigo_usuario_registro() {
    return codigo_usuario_registro;
}

public void setCodigo_usuario_registro(long codigo_usuario_registro) {
    this.codigo_usuario_registro = codigo_usuario_registro;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion(long codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion = codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion(long codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion = codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_categoria() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_categoria;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_categoria(long codigo_tipo_registro_categoria) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_categoria = codigo_tipo_registro_categoria;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_empresa() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_empresa;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_empresa(long codigo_tipo_registro_empresa) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_empresa = codigo_tipo_registro_empresa;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}





}
```

Comment: capture the http post request packet that has been sent and also post code for Usuario bean. Basically you need to check how the http params are getting mapped to Usuario bean.

Comment: the post request send two parameters to the indexController: usuario and  clave. this part works if i put  '1' in usuario parameter but if i put the name of the user 'jlhiciano' i have this exception: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.solutionslab.springboot.app.models.entity.Usuario';

Comment: can you add the com.solutionslab.springboot.app.models.entity.Usuario code in your question?

Comment: i already add the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find the solution for the problem, it's in entity usuario, i have a column named equal than the class, Usuario  for the class and usuario for username. 
I changed that and the problem was fixed.

Apparently the interpreter of the orm was confused thinking that the user field was of type class and not a string.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
private String fullname;

@NotNull
private String identificacion;

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date nacimiento;


@Column(unique=true)
private String nombre;


private String web;


private String facebook;


private String referencia;


private String instagram;


private String twitter;


private String foto;

@NotNull
private String clave;


private int codigo_postal;

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date fecha_registro;

@NotNull
private String telefono;

@NotNull
private String direccion;

@NotNull
private boolean estado;


private String detalle;


private String pasaporte;

@NotNull
private String celular;


private String whatsapp;

@NotNull
private String correo;


private long codigo_usuario_registro;


private long codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion;


private long codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion;


private long codigo_tipo_registro_categoria;


private long codigo_tipo_registro_empresa;

@NotNull
private String sexo;

/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getIdentificacion() {
    return identificacion;
}

public void setIdentificacion(String identificacion) {
    this.identificacion = identificacion;
}

public Date getNacimiento() {
    return nacimiento;
}

public void setNacimiento(Date nacimiento) {
    this.nacimiento = nacimiento;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullname;
}

public void setFullName(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
}

public String getWeb() {
    return web;
}

public void setWeb(String web) {
    this.web = web;
}

public String getFacebook() {
    return facebook;
}

public void setFacebook(String facebook) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
}

public String getReferencia() {
    return referencia;
}

public void setReferencia(String referencia) {
    this.referencia = referencia;
}

public String getInstagram() {
    return instagram;
}

public void setInstagram(String instagram) {
    this.instagram = instagram;
}

public String getTwitter() {
    return twitter;
}

public void setTwitter(String twitter) {
    this.twitter = twitter;
}

public String getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(String foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}

public String getClave() {
    return clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}

public int getCodigo_postal() {
    return codigo_postal;
}

public void setCodigo_postal(int codigo_postal) {
    this.codigo_postal = codigo_postal;
}

public Date getFecha_registro() {
    return fecha_registro;
}

public void setFecha_registro(Date fecha_registro) {
    this.fecha_registro = fecha_registro;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public boolean isEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public String getDetalle() {
    return detalle;
}

public void setDetalle(String detalle) {
    this.detalle = detalle;
}

public String getPasaporte() {
    return pasaporte;
}

public void setPasaporte(String pasaporte) {
    this.pasaporte = pasaporte;
}

public String getCelular() {
    return celular;
}

public void setCelular(String celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

public String getWhatsapp() {
    return whatsapp;
}

public void setWhatsapp(String whatsapp) {
    this.whatsapp = whatsapp;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public long getCodigo_usuario_registro() {
    return codigo_usuario_registro;
}

public void setCodigo_usuario_registro(long codigo_usuario_registro) {
    this.codigo_usuario_registro = codigo_usuario_registro;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion(long codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion = codigo_tipo_registro_clasificacion;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion(long codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion = codigo_tipo_registro_ubicacion;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_categoria() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_categoria;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_categoria(long codigo_tipo_registro_categoria) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_categoria = codigo_tipo_registro_categoria;
}

public long getCodigo_tipo_registro_empresa() {
    return codigo_tipo_registro_empresa;
}

public void setCodigo_tipo_registro_empresa(long codigo_tipo_registro_empresa) {
    this.codigo_tipo_registro_empresa = codigo_tipo_registro_empresa;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}





}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but are you saying that the issue was that you had a field names usuario inside the Class Usuario and that was causing the problem so you changed the field usuario to another name?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try specifying the attribute name in the form? like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="layout/layout :: head"></head>
<body>
    <header th:replace="layout/layout :: header"></header>
    <div class="container">
    <form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${usuario}" method="post">
        <label for="usuario">Username</label>: 
        <input type="text" th:field="*{usuario.usuario}" autofocus="autofocus" />     <br/> 
        <label for="clave">Password</label>: 
        <input type="password" th:field="*{usuario.clave}" /> <br /> 
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <footer th:replace="layout/layout :: footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be that this is a naming conflict issue (usuario type and usuario string field) at the time of binding the fields. What about changing the usuario string field name?